# Eclipse terminals(TM-Terminals) issue - java is not recoginzed

Tags: java, eclipse

I m thinking of work with "terminals" from eclipse for my eclipse project.
It seems it works as windows command prompt. But from terminal, I am not able to get the java. I am getting below error while i am trying to type "java" in terminal.

```
C:\Users\myName>java
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

When I am running same "java" from windows command prompt, it is returning the java values correctly.

what would be the issue in eclipse? Is terminals work as normal command prompt, else need to configure the command prompt in different way in eclipse?

My main purpose, I don't want to use external command prompt while I am working on eclipse IDE.

```
Environment variable details:
PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin

Eclipse.ini File:
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m

set p output in terminals:PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 61 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=3d04
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOW
S\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel
\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x
86)\CloudFoundry;C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules;C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program Fil
es\Git\bin
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files

set p from windows command prompt:
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CloudFoundry;C:\Users\Gopalan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules;C:\Users\Gopalan\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Gopalan\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 61 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=3d04
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
```

As I am new to eclipse IDE and terminals, suggest me a solution. 
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with `terminals`? A view you can open like `Window -> Show View -> Terminal-Terminal`?

Comment: Can you add the output of `set p` from your terminal?

Comment: it is TM Terminal Plugin....(termianls-->terminals.). Updated 'set p' output above.

Comment: Hope now you can see?

Comment: So, there is no java in PATH...

Answer (score 1):

Combining some of the already mentioned solutions you can achieve it as follow.

1. you define `JAVA_HOME` and the `PATH` including it as **system** variables
2. you define `JAVA_HOME` and the `PATH` including it as environment variable in the same session you start eclipse (for example in a CMD script)
   `set JAVA_HOME=...<br>
   set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%<br>
   exclipse.exe`
3. you set `JAVA_HOME` and the `PATH` including it in the preferences of the terminal
   `Window -> Preferences -> Terminal -> Local Terminal -> Variables`

other solutions still possible.

Answer (score 0):

Of which terminal are you talking? Did you install the TM Terminal plugin or something else?

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal

Comment: yes, the same one. After that i am getting from Window -> Show View -> Terminals-Terminals

Comment: OK, so that is working for me. Maybe you need to add %JAVA_HOME% to your PATH definition

Answer (score 0):

If you can use command "java" in windows terminal,you just press F11 to debug or ctrl + F11 to run program without debug.

If you cant use command "java" in windows terminal,check your *Environment Variables*.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see from output:

```
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOW
S\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel
\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x
86)\CloudFoundry;C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules;C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program Fil
es\Git\bin
```

there is no java on windows PATH...

With current version I have there:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

and in this directory there are symlinks:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 3873-EE18

 Directory of C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

2015-11-02  16:07    <DIR>          .
2015-11-02  16:07    <DIR>          ..
2015-11-02  16:07    <SYMLINK>      java.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe]
2015-11-02  16:07    <SYMLINK>      javaw.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_65\bin\javaw.exe]
2015-11-02  16:07    <SYMLINK>      javaws.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_65\bin\javaws.exe]
               3 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   2,630,152,192 bytes free
```

Comment: yes, this output is from eclipse terminals. But in my windows command prompt set p output i am able to see jdk path.

Comment: Are you using also `JAVA_HOME` - `set j` ? I can confirm, that my PATH is also not the same as from windows command line, I do not know where this difference is coming from...

Comment: Yes I added JAVA_HOME in system variable and PATH in user variable.